Почему Wordpress при загрузке фото выставляет текущую дату-время, вместо той что указываю в скрипте python?
Есть функция загрузки медиа в Wordpress:
def upload_media(file_path, timestamp):
    """ Функция загрузки фото в Wordpress """
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    dt = str(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
    print(f"Дата постинга фотографии: {dt}")
    file_path = Path(path_arh_insta + "/" + file_path)
    endpoint = f"{site_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token_wp.decode('utf-8'),
        "Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename={file_path};"
    }
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, files={'file': file, 'date': timestamp, 'caption': 'Photo Instagram', 'alt_text': 'Photo Instagram'})
        #response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, files=media)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print(f">>> Файл успешно загружен:\n>>> Код для вставки в пост: {response.json()['description']['rendered']}\n>>> ")
        return response.json()['description']['rendered']
    else:
        logger.error(f"Ошибка загрузки файла: {response.status_code}, {response.json()['message']}")
        exit ()

Файл загружается, но ни дату не ставит какую мне надо, ни описание, ни alt.
Кто делал такое подскажите что не так?

Вот тут найдёшь всё что нужно.

Ну как минимум пытаться передать дату, описание и alt в качестве файлов выглядит немножко глупо

@andreymal это был один из вариантов которые я нашел в интернете.
Про размещение постов я быстро нашел все что нужно, но с media никто не заморачивается и я нашел лишь два варианта, и оба не рабочие.

@8j0rn я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что какие-либо «варианты в интернете» реально предлагают пихать не-файлы в параметр с названием files

@andreymal я то же не мог подумать такое, вот неглядя и скопировал. Теперь сижу разбираюсь.

@andreymal нашел рабочий вариант, но в нем сначала загружается файл как есть, затем редактируется добавляя описание и alt. Мне такой вариант не подходит, поскольку если при загрузке не указывать дату, то фото ляжет не в ту папку что мне надо.

@andreymal спасибо за направление, помогло. Правда не решило задачи как я хотел, но это уже место для другого вопросу сообществу.

Спасибо, @andreymal подсказал, и я в итоге сам разобрался:
def upload_media(file_path, timestamp):
    """ Функция загрузки фото в Wordpress """
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    dt = str(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
    print(f"Дата постинга фотографии: {dt}")
    file_path = Path(path_arh_insta + "/" + file_path)
    endpoint = f"{site_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token_wp.decode('utf-8'),
        "Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename={file_path};"
    }
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, files={'file': file}, data={'date': dt, 'caption': 'Photo Instagram', 'alt_text': 'Photo Instagram'})
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print(f">>> Файл успешно загружен:\n>>> Код для вставки в пост: {response.json()['description']['rendered']}\n>>> ")
        return response.json()['description']['rendered']
    else:
        logger.error(f"Ошибка загрузки файла: {response.status_code}, {response.json()['message']}")
        exit ()

Исправил строку:
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, files={'file': file, 'date': timestamp, 'caption': 'Photo Instagram', 'alt_text': 'Photo Instagram'})

на строку:
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, files={'file': file}, data={'date': dt, 'caption': 'Photo Instagram', 'alt_text': 'Photo Instagram'})

Так же в data={} можно добавить 'id' - АйДи поста к которому будет прикриплена фотография, 'link' - Ссылка на пост, 'slug' - Буквенно-цифровой идентификатор сообщения, уникальный для его типа, 'description' - Описание фото, и другие. (Подробнее здесь)

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

@aleksandr-barakin хорошо, постараюсь более развернуто писать.
